# Converting list of strings to floats and add 1

Tags: python, list

I have parsed my input to this list:

```
lst = ['6,3', '3,2', '9,6', '4,3']
```

How to change this list of strings to a list of floats? While the numbers that are nw strings are not seperated by a . but by a ,

After that i would like to add 1 to every float. So that the ouput becomes:

```
lst = [7.3, 4.2, 10.6, 5.4]
```

Comment: It would be nice to be able to use a locale sensitive method to convert these strings to floats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
l2 = [float(num.replace(',', '.')) + 1 for num in lst]
```

First you replace comma by dot in string, after that you cast to float and add 1 to result. Operation is perfomed for each element in list.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`locale.atof(string)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.atof) which is a function designed to convert a string to a float, taking into account the locale settings, *i.e.* taking into account that in some cultures/languages the comma is used to make the decimal point, as opposed to a period.

The [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for this would then be something like this

```
from locale import atof

a = ['6,3', '3,2', '9,6', '4,3']
b = [atof(i) + 1 for i in a]
```

Unfortunately, I cannot test that it works with a comma as my locale is set to use a period.

If you don't want to use `locale.atof` then the code below will do a similar job by converting the comma to a period. You can replace the comma with a period using [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

```
a = ['6,3', '3,2', '9,6', '4,3']
b = [float(i.replace(',', '.')) + 1 for i in a]
# [7.3, 4.2, 10.6, 5.3]
```

This list comprehension is equivalent to

```
a = ['6,3', '3,2', '9,6', '4,3']
b = []
for i in a:
    j = float(i.replace(',', '.')) + 1
    b.append(j)
```

Comment: ​+1 and you can check your method with: `import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_DK.UTF-8'); print locale.atof('3,141')`

Comment: note that the implementation of `atof` pretty much just does the lame string replace anyway ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension:

```
lst = ['6,3', '3,2', '9,6', '4,3']
new_lst = [float(num.replace(',','.')) + 1 for num in lst]
```